# Calculation of distances in WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

Using Python 3.5, NLTK, and WordNet (latest version), I am calculating wup_similarity() between all synset pairs of the words "continuous" and "ongoing". Each distance is "None" even though the plain English meanings of these two words do seem similar. I also noticed that the parts of speech of these words are "adjective" and "adjective satellite", respectively.

Is the calculation failure due to parts of speech being different?
Is there a way to somehow combine these two parts of speech to circumvent the problem?

Thank you much in advance. My code snippet is given below.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
sl1 = wn.synsets("continuous")
sl2 = wn.synsets("ongoing")
for x in sl1:
    for y in sl2:
        print(x, y, x.wup_similarity(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any "failure" as in like error being raised.

It would however return `None` though, e.g.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
sl1 = wn.synsets("dog")
sl2 = wn.synsets("cat")
for x in sl1:
    for y in sl2:
        print(x, y, x.wup_similarity(y))
```

[out]:

```
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat.n.01') 0.8571428571428571
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('guy.n.01') 0.631578947368421
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat.n.03') 0.631578947368421
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('kat.n.01') 0.25
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat-o'-nine-tails.n.01') 0.42105263157894735
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('caterpillar.n.02') 0.4
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('big_cat.n.01') 0.8571428571428571
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('computerized_tomography.n.01') 0.1
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat.v.01') None
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('vomit.v.01') None
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('cat.n.01') 0.48
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('guy.n.01') 0.5714285714285714
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('cat.n.03') 0.5714285714285714
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('kat.n.01') 0.4
...
```

You could simply check for None and assign it to zero, e.g.

```
sl1 = wn.synsets("dog")
sl2 = wn.synsets("cat")
for x in sl1:
    for y in sl2:
        score = x.wup_similarity(y)
        score = score if score else 0
        print(x, y, score)
```

[out]:

```
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat.n.01') 0.8571428571428571
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('guy.n.01') 0.631578947368421
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat.n.03') 0.631578947368421
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('kat.n.01') 0.25
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat-o'-nine-tails.n.01') 0.42105263157894735
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('caterpillar.n.02') 0.4
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('big_cat.n.01') 0.8571428571428571
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('computerized_tomography.n.01') 0.1
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('cat.v.01') 0
Synset('dog.n.01') Synset('vomit.v.01') 0
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('cat.n.01') 0.48
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('guy.n.01') 0.5714285714285714
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('cat.n.03') 0.5714285714285714
Synset('frump.n.01') Synset('kat.n.01') 0.4
```

Comment: By failure I did not mean code-level failure as in exceptions, but I mean semantic failure in that the answer was "None", that is the algorithm did not generate an answer, even though the program did. WordNet provides "None" as similarity when the POS trees of the two words do not meet. This would happen if we try to find similarity between a noun and a verb. In my question, two seemingly similar words which most people will think of as being adjectives are of different POSs, namely, "adjective" and "adjective satellite". I wonder what the purpose is of these two POSs and how to get around it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817396/what-part-of-speech-does-s-stand-for-in-wordnet-synsets

Comment: and there's no easy way to get around the `s` vs `a` when trying to get similarity/distance scores. Return None or 0.