# WordNetLemmatizer: Different handling of wn.ADJ and wn.ADJ_SAT?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I need to lemmatize text using nltk. In order to do this, I apply `nltk.pos_tag` to each sentence and then convert the resulting Penn Treebank tags (http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) to WordNet tags. I need to do this because `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()` expects both the word and its correct pos_tag as arguments, otherwise it will just assume everything is a verb.

I just found that there are five different tags defined in WordNet:

- wn.VERB
- wn.ADV
- wn.NOUN
- wn.ADJ
- wn.ADJ_SAT

However, **every example I found on the internet just ignores wn.ADJ_SAT** when converting Treebank tags to WordNet tags. They are all just mapping Penn tags to WordNet tags like this:

- If Penn tag starts with J: convert to wn.ADJ
- If Penn tag starts with V: convert to wn.VERB
- If Penn tag starts with N: convert to wn.NOUN
- If Penn tag starts with R: convert to wn.ADV

So wn.ADJ_SAT is never used.

**My question** now is if there are cases where the lemmatizer returns a different result for ADJ_SAT than for ADJ. What are examples for words that are satellite adjectives (ADJ_SAT) and no normal adjectives (ADJ)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What part of speech does "s" stand for in WordNet synsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817396/what-part-of-speech-does-s-stand-for-in-wordnet-synsets)

Answer (score 2):

**The `WordNetLemmatizer` in `NLTK` does not differentiate satellite adjectives from normal adjectives.**

`nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize` is uses ["WordNet’s built-in morphy function. Returns the input word unchanged if it cannot be found in WordNet."](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize)

In WordNet, a satellite adjective--more broadly referred to as a satellite synset--is more of a semantic label used elsewhere in WordNet than a special part-of-speech in nltk.

From the wordnet [glossary](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wngloss7wn):

> **Satellite Synset**:
>   Synset in an adjective cluster representing a concept that is similar in meaning to the concept represented by its head synset .

User `tripleee` points [out in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817396/what-part-of-speech-does-s-stand-for-in-wordnet-synsets) the following:

> adjectives are subcategorized into 'head' and 'satellite' synsets within an adjective clutser

Also, [the `nltk` documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize) for `nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize` assumes the default part of speech to be a noun instead of a verb, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @Simon-h does this answer your question or am I way off?

Comment: An example would complete your answer.